# how to get screens by clicking and by last screen clicking it should to previous activity

Tags: android

how to get screens by clicking and by last screen clicking it should to previous activity and following is my code.i want to modify this code as by clicking instead of scrolling.so please some one help me. this works fine but i need when i click on it should move to next,but here i got by scrolling.

```
         public class RealViewSwitcher extends ViewGroup {
         public static interface OnScreenSwitchListener {
         void onScreenSwitched(int screen);
     }
private static final int SNAP_VELOCITY = 1000;
private static final int INVALID_SCREEN = -1;
private Scroller mScroller;
private VelocityTracker mVelocityTracker;
private final static int TOUCH_STATE_REST = 0;
private final static int TOUCH_STATE_SCROLLING = 1;
private int mTouchState = TOUCH_STATE_REST;
private float mLastMotionX;
private int mTouchSlop,mMaximumVelocity,mCurrentScreen,mNextScreen = INVALID_SCREEN;
private boolean mFirstLayout = true;
private OnScreenSwitchListener mOnScreenSwitchListener;
public RealViewSwitcher(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

public RealViewSwitcher(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

private void init() {
    mScroller = new Scroller  (getContext() );
    final ViewConfiguration configuration = ViewConfiguration.get(getContext());
    mTouchSlop = configuration.getScaledTouchSlop();
    mMaximumVelocity = configuration.getScaledMaximumFlingVelocity();
}
          protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    final int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    final int widthMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);
         final int heightMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);
        final int count = getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        getChildAt(i).measure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }

    if (mFirstLayout) {
        scrollTo(mCurrentScreen * width, 0);
        mFirstLayout = false;
    }
}
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
    int childLeft = 0;
    final int count = getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        final View child = getChildAt(i);
        if (child.getVisibility() != View.GONE) {
            final int childWidth = child.getMeasuredWidth();
            child.layout(childLeft, 0, childLeft + childWidth, child.getMeasuredHeight());
            childLeft += childWidth;
        }
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    if (mVelocityTracker == null) {
        mVelocityTracker = VelocityTracker.obtain();
    }
    mVelocityTracker.addMovement(ev);
    final int action = ev.getAction();
    final float x = ev.getX();
    switch (action) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        if (!mScroller.isFinished()) {
            mScroller.abortAnimation();
        }
        mLastMotionX = x;
        mTouchState = mScroller.isFinished() ? TOUCH_STATE_REST : TOUCH_STATE_SCROLLING;
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        final int xDiff = (int) Math.abs(x - mLastMotionX);
        boolean xMoved = xDiff > mTouchSlop;
        if (xMoved) {
            mTouchState = TOUCH_STATE_SCROLLING;
        }
        if (mTouchState == TOUCH_STATE_SCROLLING) {
            final int deltaX = (int) (mLastMotionX - x);
            mLastMotionX = x;
            final int scrollX = getScrollX();
            if (deltaX < 0) {
                if (scrollX > 0) {
                    scrollBy(Math.max(-scrollX, deltaX), 0);
                }
            } else if (deltaX > 0) {
                final int availableToScroll = getChildAt(getChildCount() - 1).getRight() - scrollX - getWidth();
                if (availableToScroll > 0) {
                    scrollBy(Math.min(availableToScroll, deltaX), 0);
                }
            }
        }
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        if (mTouchState == TOUCH_STATE_SCROLLING) {
            final VelocityTracker velocityTracker = mVelocityTracker;
            velocityTracker.computeCurrentVelocity(1000, mMaximumVelocity);
            int velocityX = (int) velocityTracker.getXVelocity();

            if (velocityX > SNAP_VELOCITY && mCurrentScreen > 0) {
                snapToScreen(mCurrentScreen - 1);
            } else if (velocityX < -SNAP_VELOCITY && mCurrentScreen < getChildCount() - 1) { 
                snapToScreen(mCurrentScreen + 1);
            } else {
                snapToDestination();
            }
            if (mVelocityTracker != null) {
                mVelocityTracker.recycle();
                mVelocityTracker = null;
            }
        }

        mTouchState = TOUCH_STATE_REST;

        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
        mTouchState = TOUCH_STATE_REST;
    }
    return true;
}
private void snapToDestination() {
    final int screenWidth = getWidth();
    final int whichScreen = (getScrollX() + (screenWidth / 2)) / screenWidth;
    snapToScreen(whichScreen);
}
private void snapToScreen(int whichScreen) {
    if (!mScroller.isFinished())
        return;
    whichScreen = Math.max(0, Math.min(whichScreen, getChildCount() - 1));
    mNextScreen = whichScreen;
    final int newX = whichScreen * getWidth();
    final int delta = newX - getScrollX();
    mScroller.startScroll(getScrollX(), 0, delta, 0, Math.abs(delta) * 2);
    invalidate();
}
public void computeScroll() {
    if (mScroller.computeScrollOffset()) {
        scrollTo(mScroller.getCurrX(), mScroller.getCurrY());
        postInvalidate();
    } else if (mNextScreen != INVALID_SCREEN) {
        mCurrentScreen = Math.max(0, Math.min(mNextScreen, getChildCount() - 1));
        if (mOnScreenSwitchListener != null)
            mOnScreenSwitchListener.onScreenSwitched(mCurrentScreen);
        mNextScreen = INVALID_SCREEN;
    }
}
public int getCurrentScreen() {
    return mCurrentScreen;
}
public void setCurrentScreen(int currentScreen) {
    mCurrentScreen = Math.max(0, Math.min(currentScreen, getChildCount() - 1));
    scrollTo(mCurrentScreen * getWidth(), 0);
    invalidate();
}
public void setOnScreenSwitchListener(OnScreenSwitchListener onScreenSwitchListener) {      mOnScreenSwitchListener = onScreenSwitchListener;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `onTouchEvent` function, inside switch case `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP`, please add this after your if condition

```
  else {
      switchToScreen(mCurrentScreen + 1);
  }
```

add this function to your class

```
    private void switchToScreen(int whichScreen) {
       if (!mScroller.isFinished())
             mScroller.abortAnimation();
        whichScreen = Math.max(0, Math.min(whichScreen, getChildCount() - 1));
        mNextScreen = whichScreen;
        final int newX = whichScreen * getWidth();
        mScroller.setFinalX(newX);
        invalidate();
    }
```

Comment: it works nick.i will show to my tl and i will back dont go please.

Comment: she was busy so said to wait 2 minutes.

Comment: nick so thanks.how can i improve more knowlege in doing like this.

Comment: wc, keep on practicing dude.. you'll get it with xp

Comment: hi nick, it was fine and i got other task.i will upload that class and i will ask u dont go it is some related to ble.please dont go wait for 1 minute

Comment: nick how can i upload my 2 java classes to ask question

Comment: you can simply add your code to you question, or if they are too long try unloading your code or file to some online sharing sites

Comment: nick see this http://stackoverflow.com/posts/22906710/edit in this i pasted half of my device scan activity

Comment: wait nick i am pasting.devicecontrolactivity

Comment: hi nick check this link i uploaded both devicescan activity and device controlactivity http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22906710/how-to-add-small-circle-connecting-pop-up-menu-when-i-click-on-item

Comment: reply nick i got other question.

Comment: nick please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23005637/how-to-fill-the-color-of-image-according-to-percentage-of-textview-in-android

Comment: nick u will not help me? r u busy.

Comment: hi nick,where r u please check this linkhttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/23005637/how-to-fill-the-color-of-image-according-to-percentage-of-textview-in-android

Comment: hi nick,if u free check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23052877/how-to-add-progress-bar-or-look-like-similar-one-in-android

Comment: hi nick,please check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23053164/how-to-save-toggle-button-state-to-database-and-if-user-edits-then-edited-state

Comment: hi nick did u forgot me?say

Comment: hi nick, please check this link it is urgent task for me.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23076353/how-to-notify-characteristics-for-every-5secs-and-update-in-android

Comment: hi nick, please help me,once check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23901986/spinner-not-displaying-telugu-font