# how to get previous activity after scrolling last screen

Tags: android

how to get previous activity after scrolling last screen.in the following code i did as when last screen i wrote intent to call previous activity it was calling but it refresh all data in that and calling all the fields in that as null and calling i want to call as before calling how it is like that only.when i press backpress at bottom it is fine it getting the previous activity but when i call activity it gets null values.

```
                protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.learnmore);

    realViewSwitcher=(com.RealViewSwitcher)findViewById(R.id.realviewswitcher);

    mainlayout=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainlayout);
    final int[] backgrounds = { R.drawable.braven_1_bankpercentage,R.drawable.braven_2_outputs,
            R.drawable.braven_3_findme,R.drawable.braven_4_sos,R.drawable.braven_5_bearmode};
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        TextView textView = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        try{
        textView.setBackgroundResource(backgrounds[i]);
        }

        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        realViewSwitcher.addView(textView);
    }

    realViewSwitcher.setOnScreenSwitchListener(onScreenSwitchListener);

}



private final RealViewSwitcher.OnScreenSwitchListener onScreenSwitchListener = new RealViewSwitcher.OnScreenSwitchListener() {

    @Override
    public void onScreenSwitched(int screen) {
        if(screen==5)
        {
            Intent intent=new Intent(LearnMore.this,DeviceControlActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        }
        Log.d("RealViewSwitcher", "switched to screen: " + screen);
    }

};
```

Comment: why you are calling `startActivityForResult()`?

Comment: How about `finish` as it is previous activity. So it will resume!

Comment: ok i should call only startactivity()

Comment: i added onresume() in previous activity

Comment: did you just want to go back to previous `Activity` or start a new `Activity`?

Comment: i got solution. just to go back i follow the nick answer as in following.thanks

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22861515/how-to-get-screens-by-clicking-and-by-last-screen-clicking-it-should-to-previous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are starting prev activity again using `startActivityForResult` thats why you are getting your data refreshed for prev activity, so instead of calling it again you should call `Activity.finish()` on this activity so that it will open your prev activity with old data.

Your prev Activity will be added to stack when you start your current activity, so when you call finish on your current activity, os will kill this activity & pop prev activity from stack and retain its view. But here as you are calling `startActivityForResult` so it will prev activity afresh and push your current activity to stack

simply replace

```
      Intent intent=new Intent(LearnMore.this,DeviceControlActivity.class);
      startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

with

`finish()`

Comment: please add some code how to write activity.finish()

Comment: you can simply call finish(), instead of 

        Intent intent=new Intent(LearnMore.this,DeviceControlActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

Comment: thanks it works.and i had another issue.that is now i am scrolling the screens but i want both by scrolling and when i click on it also it should move to next above is one class from that i am calling http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22861515/how-to-get-screens-by-clicking-and-by-last-screen-clicking-it-should-to-previous

Comment: once check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22861515/how-to-get-screens-by-clicking-and-by-last-screen-clicking-it-should-to-previous and help me.

Comment: nick otherwise use only on tap/click on surface it should move to next screen.

Comment: please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23005637/how-to-fill-the-color-of-image-according-to-percentage-of-textview-in-android/23005844?noredirect=1#comment35138813_23005844

Comment: hi nick please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23009657/how-to-change-the-image-color-in-imageview-according-to-percentage-and-fill-colo