# how to change the image color in imageview according to percentage and fill color upto that percentage

Tags: android

How to fill the image according to percentage of `TextView`. and it should change according to percentage of `TextView` .in the following code the height layout is changing but i want the color of image should change according to percentage(value of textview(battery)).

**CODE:**

```
 private void displayData(String data) {
    if (data != null) { 
        battery.setText(data);
  int x=Integer.parseInt(battery.getText().toString());
  image_level.getLayoutParams().height = x;
    }
 }
```

This is my `TextView` i am getting data as 100 or some 60 like that.what ever value i got that much level my `ImageView` should fill with color and display.

```
<TextView  android:id="@+id/batterylevel"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="150dp"
 android:text="BRV Battery" 
 android:layout_below="@+id/sos"/>

<ImageView 
 android:id="@+id/image_level"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="100dp"
 android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" 
 android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/batterylevel"
 android:layout_below="@+id/sos"
 android:layout_above="@+id/portbearmode"
 android:alpha="1"
 android:adjustViewBounds="true"
 android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"/>
```

in the layout i did like this i should apply any animations or simply setting any options please tell me.
if battery `TextView` is 60 it should fill blue color upto 60 and remaining 40 as white color.

Comment: use LayerDrawable with two child Drawables: a ClipDrawable and BitmapDrawable

Comment: how can u explain clearly i will get the value in display data and according to that value(%) i have to fill the color of image in imageview

Comment: create a LayerDrawable ld; and call ld.setLevel(level) where level is in [0..10000] range

Comment: how to create layerdrawable.

Comment: by calling its constructor? new LayerDrawable(...

Comment: i dont have constructor.

Comment: i didnot got it.see in the above code where i can add layerdrawable

Comment: you dont have constructor? well i think you should really take some basic java lessons

Comment: means in this class i didnot created constructor

Comment: hi please check your previous question