# how to add small circle connecting pop up menu when i click on item

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

how to add small circle like pop up menu(like it rolls and display text connecting )when after moving to that particular item it should display connected/disconnected(when connected)successfully.now following is my devicescan activity.in this i will get list of all ble devices. here is my devicescanactivity

```
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getActionBar().setTitle("BLE Devices");

    UUIDS=new UUID[]{(UUID.fromString("0000180f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb")) };


    mHandler = new Handler();
    db = new DataBaseAdapter(this);

    // Use this check to determine whether BLE is supported on the device.  Then you can
    // selectively disable BLE-related features.
    if (!getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH_LE)) {
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.ble_not_supported, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();
    }

    // Initializes a Bluetooth adapter.  For API level 18 and above, get a reference to
    // BluetoothAdapter through BluetoothManager.
    final BluetoothManager bluetoothManager =
            (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
    mBluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();

    // Checks if Bluetooth is supported on the device.
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
        finish();
        return;
    }
        }




@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onRestart();

    if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
        }
    }
     // Initializes list view adapter.
    mLeDeviceListAdapter = new LeDeviceListAdapter();
    setListAdapter(mLeDeviceListAdapter);
    scanLeDevice(true);
  }
    @Override
 protected void onResume() {
           super.onResume();


    if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
        }
    }

    // Initializes list view adapter.
    mLeDeviceListAdapter = new LeDeviceListAdapter();
    setListAdapter(mLeDeviceListAdapter);
    scanLeDevice(true);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // User chose not to enable Bluetooth.
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_ENABLE_BT && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
        finish();
        return;
    }
     super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    scanLeDevice(false);
    mLeDeviceListAdapter.clear();
} 

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    final BluetoothDevice device = mLeDeviceListAdapter.getDevice(position);

    if (device == null) return;
    UUI D deviceUuid = new UUID(device.hashCode(), ((long)device.hashCode() << 32)  );

    String deviceUUID = deviceUuid.toString();

    db.open();
        Cursor c;
        c=db.getData();

            while (c != null && c.moveToNext())
            {
           if(deviceUUID.equalsIgnoreCase(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("uuid"))))

                    {
        sname = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("devicename"));
        sLight= c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("light"));
        sAlarm= c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("alarm"));  
                    }
                else{


                }
                }
    db.close();
     Intent intent = new Intent(this, DeviceControlActivity.class);

     intent.putExtra(DeviceControlActivity.EXTRAS_DEVICE_NAME, sname);
     intent.putExtra(DeviceControlActivity.EXTRAS_DEVICE_ADDRESS,device.getAddress());
     intent.putExtra(DeviceControlActivity.EXTRAS_DEVICE_UUID, deviceUUID);
     intent.putExtra(DeviceControlActivity.EXTRAS_DEVICE_LIGHT, sLight);
     intent.putExtra(DeviceControlActivity.EXTRAS_DEVICE_ALARM, sAlarm);
    if (mScanning) {
        mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
        mScanning = false;
    }
  startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
}

    private void scanLeDevice(final boolean enable) {
    if (enable) {
        // Stops scanning after a pre-defined scan period.
        mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mScanning = false;
                mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        }, SCAN_PERIOD);

        mScanning = true;
        mBluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(mLeScanCallback);

    } else {
        mScanning = false;
        mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
    }
    invalidateOptionsMenu();
     }

   // Adapter for holding devices found through scanning.
   private class LeDeviceListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> mLeDevices;
    private LayoutInflater mInflator;

    public LeDeviceListAdapter() {
        super();
        mLeDevices = new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>();
        mInflator = DeviceScanActivity.this.getLayoutInflater();
    }

     public void addDevice(BluetoothDevice device) {
        if(!mLeDevices.contains(device)&& device.getName().startsWith("BRV")) {


            mLeDevices.add(device);
        }
    }

    public BluetoothDevice getDevice(int position) {
        return mLeDevices.get(position);
    }

    public void clear() {
        mLeDevices.clear();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mLeDevices.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return mLeDevices.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        // General ListView optimization code.
        if (view == null) {
            view = mInflator.inflate(R.layout.listitem_device, null);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.deviceAddress = (TextView)    
           view.findViewById(R.id.device_address);            
            viewHolder.deviceName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.device_name);
            view.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        BluetoothDevice device = mLeDevices.get(i);
        String deviceName = device.getName();
        UUID deviceUuid = new UUID(device.hashCode(), ((long)device.hashCode() << 32));              
        String deviceId = deviceUuid.toString();

        if (deviceName != null && deviceName.length() > 0){
             db.open();
        if(db!=null)
        {
             Cursor c;
             c=db.getData();
             String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM DeviceDetails";
                c = db.select(selectQuery);
                while (c != null && c.moveToNext())
                {
          if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
            if(deviceId.equalsIgnoreCase(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("uuid"))))
                    {
            viewHolder.deviceName.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("devicename")));
                    }

                } while (c.moveToNext());
            }
           else {
            viewHolder.deviceName.setText("noname");
        }             
        }

        }

        db.close();

        }
        else

            viewHolder.deviceName.setText("unknown_device");
        viewHolder.deviceAddress.setText(device.getAddress());



        return view;

    }
   }

     // Device scan callback.
          private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mLeScanCallback =
        new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, int rssi, byte[] scanRecord) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                try{
                mLeDeviceListAdapter.addDevice(device);
                mLeDeviceListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();}
                catch(Exception e){

                }
            }
        });
    }
      };
      //Scanning for a particualr UUID 
         // Device scan callback.
          private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mLeScanCallback_particular =
        new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, int rssi, byte[] scanRecord) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mLeDeviceListAdapter.addDevice(device);
                mLeDeviceListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }
};
static class ViewHolder {
    TextView deviceName;
    TextView deviceAddress;
}
```

and from this class when i click item it moves to the devicecontrol activity so it is as follows.when i click it should moves to the devicecontrol activity and it should popup small menu like circle in it and display text like connecting.and after connnecting it was successful.

```
            private final ServiceConnection mServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection()        
       {
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName componentName, IBinder service) {
        mBluetoothLeService = ((BluetoothLeService.LocalBinder) service).getService();
        if (!mBluetoothLeService.initialize()) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Unable to initialize Bluetooth");
             finish();
        }
        // Automatically connects to the device upon successful start-up initialization.
        mBluetoothLeService.connect(mDeviceAddress);
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName componentName) {
        mBluetoothLeService = null;

    }
   };
    private final BroadcastReceiver mGattUpdateReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        final String action = intent.getAction();
        if (BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED.equals(action)) {
            mConnected = true;
            updateConnectionState(R.string.connected);
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        } else if (BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED.equals(action)) {
            mConnected = false;
            updateConnectionState(R.string.disconnected);
             invalidateOptionsMenu();
             create_alert();
        } else if (BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED.equals(action)) {
              Log.e(TAG, "Services Discovered");
              check_forservices(mBluetoothLeService.getSupportedGattServices());
        } else if (BluetoothLeService.ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE.equals(action)) {
            displayData(intent.getStringExtra(BluetoothLeService.EXTRA_DATA));

        }
    }
};

private BluetoothLeService mBluetoothGatt;

  private void clearUI() {
    mGattServicesList.setAdapter((SimpleExpandableListAdapter) null);
    mDataField.setText(R.string.no_data);
 }
      @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.gatt_services_characteristics);
 ........  
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.d(TAG,"In resume");
    boolean result = false;
    registerReceiver(mGattUpdateReceiver, makeGattUpdateIntentFilter());
    if (mBluetoothLeService != null) {
        result = mBluetoothLeService.connect(mDeviceAddress);
        Log.d(TAG, "Connect request result=" + result);
    }
    Intent gattServiceIntent = new Intent(this, BluetoothLeService.class);
    bindService(gattServiceIntent, mServiceConnection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

 }


protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    unregisterReceiver(mGattUpdateReceiver);
}

protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    unbindService(mServiceConnection);
    mBluetoothLeService = null;
    try{
      }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    }

 }
  private void updateConnectionState(final int resourceId) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
        }
    });
}

private void displayData(String data) {
    Log.d("No serives",data );
    if (data != null) { 
        battery.setText(data);
    }
}
    //Check for LEUCP servie

  private void  check_forservices(List<BluetoothGattService> gattServices){
   if (gattServices == null) return;
   String uuid = null;
   String unknownServiceString = getResources().getString(R.string.unknown_service);
   String unknownCharaString =getResources().getString(R.string.unknown_characteristic);
   ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> gattServiceData = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,            String>>();
   ArrayList<ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> gattCharacteristicData
           = new ArrayList<ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>>();
   mGattCharacteristics = new ArrayList<ArrayList<BluetoothGattCharacteristic>>();

   // Loops through available GATT Services.
   for (BluetoothGattService gattService : gattServices) {
       HashMap<String, String> currentServiceData = new HashMap<String, String>();
       uuid = gattService.getUuid().toString();
       Log.d("Service UUID::",uuid);

       if(uuid.equalsIgnoreCase(SampleGattAttributes.SIMPLE_KEYS_SERVICE)){
           currentServiceData.put(
                   LIST_NAME, SampleGattAttributes.lookup(uuid, unknownServiceString));
           currentServiceData.put(LIST_UUID, uuid);
           gattServiceData.add(currentServiceData);

           ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> gattCharacteristicGroupData =
                   new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
           List<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> gattCharacteristics =
                   gattService.getCharacteristics();
           ArrayList<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> charas =
                   new ArrayList<BluetoothGattCharacteristic>();


           // Loops through available Characteristics.
           for (BluetoothGattCharacteristic gattCharacteristic : gattCharacteristics) {


               charas.add(gattCharacteristic);
               HashMap<String, String> currentCharaData = new HashMap<String, String>();
               uuid = gattCharacteristic.getUuid().toString();
                                          currentCharaData.put(LIST_NAME,SampleGattAttributes.lookup(uuid,unknownCharaString));
               currentCharaData.put(LIST_UUID, uuid);
               gattCharacteristicGroupData.add(currentCharaData);
               int charrec=gattCharacteristic.getProperties();
                  if ((charrec | BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_WRITE) > 0) {

                       Log.d("characterisitc UUID::",uuid+"....."+SampleGattAttributes.PORT1_CHARACTERSITIC);
                              if(uuid.equalsIgnoreCase(SampleGattAttributes.PORT1_CHARACTERSITIC.toString())){
                          check_port_1=1;

                             if(port1.isChecked())
                             {   
                                   }
                       }
                      else if(uuid.equalsIgnoreCase(SampleGattAttributes.PORT2_CHARACTERSITIC.toString())){
                          check_port_2=1;
                                 if(port1.isChecked())
                             {   
                    }
                       }

                      else  if(uuid.equalsIgnoreCase(SampleGattAttributes.FINDME_CHARACTERSITIC.toString())){

                        find_me=1;
                       }
               }
                }

           mGattCharacteristics.add(charas);

           gattCharacteristicData.add(gattCharacteristicGroupData);
       }
      if(uuid.equalsIgnoreCase(SampleGattAttributes.BATTERY_SERVICE)){
          currentServiceData.put(
                  LIST_NAME, SampleGattAttributes.lookup(uuid, unknownServiceString));
          currentServiceData.put(LIST_UUID, uuid);
          gattServiceData.add(currentServiceData);

          ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> gattCharacteristicGroupData =
                  new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
          List<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> gattCharacteristics =
                  gattService.getCharacteristics();
          ArrayList<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> charas =
                  new ArrayList<BluetoothGattCharacteristic>();

          // Loops through available Characteristics.
          for (BluetoothGattCharacteristic gattCharacteristic : gattCharacteristics) {
              charas.add(gattCharacteristic);
              HashMap<String, String> currentCharaData = new HashMap<String, String>();
              uuid = gattCharacteristic.getUuid().toString();

              currentCharaData.put(LIST_NAME, SampleGattAttributes.lookup(uuid, unknownCharaString));
              currentCharaData.put(LIST_UUID, uuid);
              gattCharacteristicGroupData.add(currentCharaData);
              int charrec=gattCharacteristic.getProperties();
```

if(uuid.equalsIgnoreCase(SampleGattAttributes.CLIENT_CHARACTERISTIC_CONFIG_BATTERY)){
                      Log.d("Matching battery %","");
                    char_write=uuid;
                     byte[] values={2,1,0,7,0,0,0};

```
                 if ((charrec | BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_READ) > 0) {

                     if (mNotifyCharacteristic != null) {
                         mBluetoothLeService.setCharacteristicNotification(
                                 mNotifyCharacteristic, false);
                         mNotifyCharacteristic = null;
                     }
                     mBluetoothLeService.readCharacteristic(gattCharacteristic);
                 }
                 if ((charrec | BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_NOTIFY) > 0) {
                     mNotifyCharacteristic = gattCharacteristic;
                     mBluetoothLeService.setCharacteristicNotification(gattCharacteristic, true);
                 }

                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        DeviceControlActivity.this);

                    // set title
alertDialogBuilder.setTitle(" Service has charactersitic:"+charrec);

                    // set dialog message
      alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Click yes to                                           exit!").setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {

                            }
                          });


                        // create alert dialog
                        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

                    }

               }

          mGattCharacteristics.add(charas);

          gattCharacteristicData.add(gattCharacteristicGroupData);
      }
          }


}
// Demonstrates how to iterate through the supported GATT Services/Characteristics.
// In this sample, we populate the data structure that is bound to the ExpandableListView
// on the UI.
private void displayGattServices(List<BluetoothGattService> gattServices) {
    if (gattServices == null) return;
    String uuid = null;
    String unknownServiceString = getResources().getString(R.string.unknown_service);
    String unknownCharaString = getResources().getString(R.string.unknown_characteristic);
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> gattServiceData = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    ArrayList<ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> gattCharacteristicData
            = new ArrayList<ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>>();
    mGattCharacteristics = new ArrayList<ArrayList<BluetoothGattCharacteristic>>();

    // Loops through available GATT Services.
    for (BluetoothGattService gattService : gattServices) {
        HashMap<String, String> currentServiceData = new HashMap<String, String>();
        uuid = gattService.getUuid().toString();

        currentServiceData.put(
                LIST_NAME, SampleGattAttributes.lookup(uuid, unknownServiceString));
        currentServiceData.put(LIST_UUID, uuid);
        gattServiceData.add(currentServiceData);

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> gattCharacteristicGroupData =
                new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        List<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> gattCharacteristics =
                gattService.getCharacteristics();
        ArrayList<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> charas =
                new ArrayList<BluetoothGattCharacteristic>();

        // Loops through available Characteristics.
        for (BluetoothGattCharacteristic gattCharacteristic : gattCharacteristics) {


            charas.add(gattCharacteristic);
            HashMap<String, String> currentCharaData = new HashMap<String, String>();
            uuid = gattCharacteristic.getUuid().toString();
            currentCharaData.put(
                    LIST_NAME, SampleGattAttributes.lookup(uuid, unknownCharaString));
            currentCharaData.put(LIST_UUID, uuid);
            gattCharacteristicGroupData.add(currentCharaData);

            if(uuid.equals(SampleGattAttributes.BATTERY_SERVICE)){
                char_write=uuid;
                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        DeviceControlActivity.this);


                    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Battery Service has charactersitic:"+char_write);
                    alertDialogBuilder
                        .setMessage("Click yes to exit!")
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                                DeviceControlActivity.this.finish();
                            }
                          });


                        // create alert dialog
                        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

                        // show it
                          alertDialog.show();
                    }

             }

        mGattCharacteristics.add(charas);
        gattCharacteristicData.add(gattCharacteristicGroupData);
    }

    SimpleExpandableListAdapter gattServiceAdapter = new SimpleExpandableListAdapter(
            this,
            gattServiceData,
            android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_2,
            new String[] {LIST_NAME, LIST_UUID},
            new int[] { android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 },
            gattCharacteristicData,
            android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_2,
            new String[] {LIST_NAME, LIST_UUID},
            new int[] { android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 }
    );
    mGattServicesList.setAdapter(gattServiceAdapter);
}

private static IntentFilter makeGattUpdateIntentFilter() {
    final IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction(BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED);
    intentFilter.addAction(BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED);
    intentFilter.addAction(BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED);
    intentFilter.addAction(BluetoothLeService.ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE);
    return intentFilter;
}


       @Override
      public void onContentChanged()
          {
super.onContentChanged();

       }

 protected void onRestart() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    super.onRestart();
}
 public void create_alert(){

    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            DeviceControlActivity.this);

        // set title
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Alert");

        // set dialog message
        alertDialogBuilder
            .setMessage("The connection to device was lost. Please reconnect in the device settings menu.")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Ok",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                       finish();
                }
              }
            )
              .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                }
            });

        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
             alertDialog.show();
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_connect:
            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(DeviceControlActivity.this, "", "Connecting...");

            new Thread() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

            try{
                 mBluetoothLeService.connect(mDeviceAddress);
            sleep(20000);

            } catch (Exception e) {

            Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());

            }

            // dismiss the progress dialog

            progressDialog.dismiss();

            }

            }.start();


          //  Toast.makeText(DeviceControlActivity.this,"Connecting...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;
        case R.id.menu_disconnect:
            mBluetoothLeService.disconnect();
             return true;
        case android.R.id.home:
            onBackPressed();
            return true;

    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

     if(requestCode == 0 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        String position = data.getStringExtra("Daddress");
        String newName = data.getStringExtra("Dname");
        String newlight = data.getStringExtra("Dlight");
        String newalarm = data.getStringExtra("Dalarm");

      title_text.setText(newName);
       mDeviceName=newName;
         mDeviceLight=newlight;
```

mDeviceAlarm=newalarm;

```
     }

      if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {

          finish();
          return;

      }
      super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [Crouton](http://johnkil.github.io/Android-AppMsg/). You can apply styles to it, i.e. make it round popup with text.

Comment: please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23005637/how-to-fill-the-color-of-image-according-to-percentage-of-textview-in-android/23005844?noredirect=1#comment35138813_23005844